# How to call from function to another function

Tags: python

I am making a minesweeper game within python with pygame.

```
import pygame, math, sys

def bomb_check():
    if check in BOMBS:
    print("You hit a bomb!")
    sys.exit

def handle_mouse(mousepos):
    x, y = mousepos
    x, y = math.ceil(x / 40), math.ceil(y / 40)
    check = print("("+"{0}, {1}".format(x,y)+")")
```

I want to call "check" to "bomb_check"
Any other solution to this problem is welcome, I am but a rookie at python.

Comment: Are check and BOMBS defined globally? As written then you should just inline the two functions. A more general solution is to return a Boolean from check and then call it with check(coordinate)

Comment: `print` returns `None`, so `check` here is not getting a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it as an argument:

```
import pygame, math, sys

def bomb_check(check):
    if check in BOMBS:
    print("You hit a bomb!")
    sys.exit

def handle_mouse(mousepos):
    x, y = mousepos
    x, y = math.ceil(x / 40), math.ceil(y / 40)
    check = x, y
    print(check)
    bomb_check(check)
```

That will work only if you are storing a tuples of 2 items (integers) in your BOMBS. Of course it also requires BOMBS to be in global scope.

Comment: @L.deBoer if that answer satisfy your needs, accept it.

Comment: @vishes_shell I had to wait some manditory ammount of time, just got my connection back.